# Sound recorder does not work

Tags: windows-7, audio

When I click on its icon in the start menu, I get this error:

> An audio recording device cannot be found.

When I say "OK", I see this setting:

[image]

What am I supposed to do there?

I have no idea what has happened and what should I do to fix it. It was working till an hour ago.

Comment: To be able to answer this question completely we may require further information, what operating system are you running and have you made any changes to the system. Do other people have access to your system that could have changed the settings by accident or even do you have another sound device e.g. Pci sound card that conflicts with your on board one?

Comment: Make/Model of computer? Windows 7 32 or 64 bit?  Did you happen to allow Windows Update to install a hardware driver recently

Comment: [Vaio VPCS116FG](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/VPCS116FG), 64 bit. I'm not sure about the last question, it didn't ask for my permission!

Comment: Please click on the Recording tab to show installed recording devices and update yje graphic in your question

Answer (score 0):

You appear not to have a device able to record audio as the microphone icon indicates.  Is the microphone disabled in Device manager? Check for it being disabled.  It may also be missing.  You may need to re-install audio drivers and/or chipset drivers [Vaio Drivers](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/VPCS116FG)